# Where is the web.xml in a Neo4j server extension?

Tags: json, rest, neo4j, jersey, jax-rs

I am working with a server extentsion for Neo4j. I got a problem with mapping POJOs to and from JSON, and found the solution in this thread:
[A message body writer for Java class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108161/a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-not-found)
The problem is that I do not have a web.xml in my project. I tried to add one, but it did not work.

Is it possible to add web.xml to a server extension plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a web.xml perhaps this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929203/consuming-json-in-neo4j-server-extension

Comment: I looked at that example and can not see why my code does not work. I have almost the exact same setup. I do not get what "<mainClass>org.civinomics.graphapi.CivGraph</mainClass>" is in the pom. Also I use neo4j 2.2.0 and not 2.2.2 as he does.

Comment: Both are unrelated, I think you need the jersey-jackson-json message converter lib that was mentioned.

Comment: I got it working. I was not aware of how to provide dependencies to Neo4J. When I added the jersey-json jar to system->lib folder it worked. I did only add it to my pom earlier.

Comment: Add it to the plugins folder together with your extension jar